# NaNs produced when taking log to numbers greater than 0

Tags: r, nan

I want to make a log variable to a variable over total assets. I do like this:

```
`HRSdata2$h1logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h1atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h1atotb), 0))`
```

and I get the error message: `In log(HRSdata2$h1atotb) : NaNs produced`

My dataset shows that I get NA's when taking log(NA) which I predicted, BUT, why do I get NaN's? They concerne me a great deal more.

Also can someone show me the code for running a loop or other smart way to apply log to a bunch of columns? Currently this is my (very poor I know) code:

```
HRSdata2$h1logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h1atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h1atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h2logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h2atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h2atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h3logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h3atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h3atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h4logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h4atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h4atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h5logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h5atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h5atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h6logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h6atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h6atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h7logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h7atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h7atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h8logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h8atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h8atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h9logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h9atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h9atotb), 0))
HRSdata2$h10logass <- (ifelse(HRSdata2$h10atotb > 0, log(HRSdata2$h10atotb), 0))
```

I basically just need to learn how to loop over variable names thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give a [mcve] in your question! Have you NA's in your data?

Comment: are there any NA in `HRSdata2$h1logass` ? Check with something like `HRSdata2[is.na(HRSdata2$h1logass),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `ifelse(x > 0, log(x), 0)`, R computes `log(x)`:

```
> x <- c(2, -1, 3)
> ifelse(x > 0, log(x), 0)
[1] 0.6931472 0.0000000 1.0986123
Warning message:
In log(x) : NaNs produced
```

But in the result you don't get the `NaN`, you get `0` for the values corresponding to `x <= 0`.

This `ifelse` statement is equivalent to

```
ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), c(log(2), log(-1), log(3)), c(0,0,0))
```

R does not drop the calculations of the values of the second argument for which the value of the first argument is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have a distaste for `ifelse` and tend to instead use two lines of code instead to fill in the default and then the alternative applied conditionally.

To loop through all your columns you can use the following code (I have not tesed it since there is no data)

```
for(i in 1:10){
    HRSdata2[,paste0('h',i,'logass')] <- 0
    w <- which(HRSdata2[,paste0('h',i,'atotb')] > 0)
    HRSdata2[w,paste0('h',i,'logass')] <-  HRSdata2[w,paste0('h',i,'atotb')]
}
```

This code will output zero for NA values,, if this is not desired the you should replace:

```
w <- which(HRSdata2[,paste0('h',i,'atotb')] > 0)
```

with:

```
w <- which(HRSdata2[,paste0('h',i,'atotb')] > 0 | is.na( HRSdata2[,paste0('h',i,'atotb')] ) )
```